# How can I dedicate something to my family and make a special note of my wife?

Tags: american-english, word-usage

In a formal media article that describes my achievements, I want to say something like the following:

> I want to dedicate this achievement/award to my family and especially
>   to my wife for all the nights she stayed up to give me company while I
>   pulled all nighthers.

The all-nighters seems a bit informal and student-ish and I am not a student. Is there a better/concise/formal way of saying this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*... for keeping me company as I worked through all those nights.*

Comment: +1 Great! Thank you. One last question - is the usage `and especially to my wife...` correct?